# getElementsByClassName and appendChild is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html

First of all, solutions must be pure VanillaJS.

I have a simple HTML code.

```
<div class="x">X</div>
<div class="x">Y</div>
<div class="x">Z</div>
```

And a VanillaJS code.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var l = document.createElement('div');
    l.innerHTML = "Hello World";
}, false);
```

When I tried to run the following code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('x')[0].appendChild(l);
```

I get the output

```
X
Hello World
Y
Z
```

Well, technically that is correct. But whenever I tried to append to another member of the array it does not work as expected.

I have tried:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('x')[0].appendChild(l);
document.getElementsByClassName('x')[1].appendChild(l);
document.getElementsByClassName('x')[2].appendChild(l);
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
X
Hello World
Y
Hello World
Z
Hello World
```

**ACTUAL OUTPUT**

```
X
Y
Z
Hello World
```

Based on my observation, only the last line of the code is considered. There were no errors in the console, it just simply not working.

I have tried another scenario of rearranging the order of the array.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('x')[1].appendChild(l);
document.getElementsByClassName('x')[2].appendChild(l);
document.getElementsByClassName('x')[0].appendChild(l);
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
X
Hello World
Y
Hello World
Z
Hello World
```

**ACTUAL OUTPUT:**

```
X
Hello World
Y
Z
```

As you can see, only the last append is considered, it does not append on the other elements with the same class name.

I also tried looping them, still no luck.

**FULL CODE:**

```
<div class="x">X</div>
<div class="x">Y</div>
<div class="x">Z</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   var l = document.createElement('div');
    l.innerHTML = "Hello World";

    document.getElementsByClassName('x')[0].appendChild(l);
    document.getElementsByClassName('x')[1].appendChild(l);
    document.getElementsByClassName('x')[2].appendChild(l);
}, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only ever create a single element:

```
var l = document.createElement('div');
```

When you use `appendChild`, if the appended element is currently a child of some other parent (eg the first `x`), when you append it to another, it gets removed from its first parent and is appended to the second. Appending the same element to multiple parents in a row will result in it only existing as a child of the last parent at the end.

Create a new element on each iteration instead (and when assigning *text* and not HTML, make sure to assign to the `textContent` property rather than the `innerHTML` property)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.x').forEach((x) => {
  var l = document.createElement('div');
  l.textContent = "Hello World";
  x.appendChild(l);
});
```

```html
<div class="x">X</div>
<div class="x">Y</div>
<div class="x">Z</div>
```

Comment: Wow. I didn't know that `appendChild` works that way. I just thought of it as a regular variable that can be used over and over again.

Comment: Yep. All non-primitives (such as objects, including HTMLElements) are essentially *references* to memory locations, and are not copied unless something explicitly copies them.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) to append copies of the created element :

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var l = document.createElement('div');
  l.innerHTML = "Hello World";

  document.getElementsByClassName('x')[0].appendChild(l.cloneNode(true));
  document.getElementsByClassName('x')[1].appendChild(l.cloneNode(true));
  document.getElementsByClassName('x')[2].appendChild(l.cloneNode(true));
}, false);
```

```html
<div class="x">X</div>
<div class="x">Y</div>
<div class="x">Z</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This occurred because you used one HTMLElement reference to add as child for all the div. One html child can be added to one parent only. So, first two parents append child appended the element, then immediately removed and finally add it as child of last div only.

I have created 3 different child for all div. Please check the following code snippet:

```html
<div class="x">X</div>
<div class="x">Y</div>
<div class="x">Z</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   var l1 = document.createElement('div');
    l1.innerHTML = "Hello World";
    var l2 = document.createElement('div');
    l2.innerHTML = "Hello World";
    var l3 = document.createElement('div');
    l3.innerHTML = "Hello World";

    document.getElementsByClassName('x')[0].appendChild(l1);
    document.getElementsByClassName('x')[1].appendChild(l2);
    document.getElementsByClassName('x')[2].appendChild(l3);
}, false);
</script>
```

Comment: @downvoter, would you please check the updated answer.

Comment: This answer is not elegant. Think of a situation where you have hundreds of elements to append to.